# Django Messages are loading only after refresh after ajax call to delete a product from wishlist

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-oscar, django-messages

In my django oscar project i have a wishlist templte which contains button to delete product from wishlist. The product is getting deleted after ajax call but the success message which is created in deleteview is loading after refreshing page.

Comment: Oscar itself doesn't use ajax to manage wishlists - so I'm guessing you have implemented this yourself? If so, you also need to implement handling of messages, otherwise they will, as you note, be rendered on the next full page load. Your options are (a) to override the view and disable use of the Django messages framework or (b) include in your ajax response any messages that are stored in the session.

Comment: @solarissmoke Im not sure how to include messages in ajax response because im using a seperate html for messages which is included in main page.

Answer (score 0):

in views.py, return

```
response = {
    'msg': render_to_string(
        'messages/wishlist-msg.html',
        {
            'message': msg,
        },
    ),
}
return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(response),
    content_type='application/json',
)
```

wishlist-msg.html

```
  <div class="message-notification">
 {{ message }}
  </div>
```

when ajax success, js file

```
const $message = $('.message-notification');
# code for ajax

    done(function (data) {
         message.append(data['msg']);
          });
```